# From nested XML to CSV using XSLT (advanced)

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I wish to transform an XML message to a CSV file, however I have some requirements of which I'm not sure I'm going to solve using XSLT.

First the original XML file:

```
<ProductInformation>
  <Products>
    <Product ID="itemid-00001" UserTypeID="objectType" ParentID="objectType2">
      <KeyValue KeyID="keyItemNumber">123456</KeyValue>
      <Name>123456</Name>
      <AttributeLink AttributeID="sizeNumeric" Inherited="2">
                
        <MetaData>
          <Value AttributeID="sequence">2</Value>
          <Value AttributeID="CPS" ID="1">1</Value>
        </MetaData>

      </AttributeLink>
      <AttributeLink AttributeID="primaryColor" Inherited="2">
                
        <MetaData>
          <Value AttributeID="sequence">3</Value>
          <Value AttributeID="CPS" ID="1">1</Value>
        </MetaData>

      </AttributeLink>
      <AttributeLink AttributeID="secondaryColour_" Inherited="2">
                
        <MetaData>
          <Value AttributeID="sequence">10</Value>
        </MetaData>

      </AttributeLink>

      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="sizeNumeric">0.01</Value>
        <Value AttributeID="secondaryColour_" ID="Red">Red</Value>
      </Values>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</ProductInformation>
```

From this XML file I wish to retrieve the values for all attributelinks which have a CPS score of 1. I want to create an extra column in my CSV for each attributelink that has a CPS property of 1. Then I want to put the matching values in the correct column. This XML will also contain multiple items which can all have their own unique attributeLinks and corresponding CPS-scores.

In this example the resulting CSV file should look like this;

```
Item;sizeNumeric;primaryColor
123456;0.01;;
```

Is something like this possible to do using XSLT?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So each `Product` in the XML maps to a line in the CSV? As for the header lines, if "multiple items which can all have their own unique attributeLinks and corresponding CPS-scores" do you simply output  a new header line of column names for each `Product`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen indeed! Each product will have their own attributeLinks and CPS scores. An item/rproduct can have the same links as a previous one, but these can also differ. I think prefereably I would like to keep adding header columns for each new attributeLink with a CPS score of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:key name="score" match="Product/AttributeLink/@AttributeID" use="../MetaData/Value[@AttributeID = 'CPS']"/>
    
  <xsl:key name="value" match="Product/Values/Value" use="@AttributeID"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="//Product ! 
              (let $columns := key('score', '1')
              return (
                ('Item', $columns) => string-join(';'),
                (Name, $columns ! string(key('value', .))) => string-join(';')
              ))" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGN